# How to Secure mobile web-service and its content?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, mobile, encryption

I have a web-service which is used to create entries in the Database hosted by GoDaddy and the web-service are written in .net and this web-service or url will be only used in the Mobile Platforms like IOS and Android.

**Now I have few questions?**

1>How can I secure my URL(web-service) and its content from getting exposed? 
  Currently I have used post method so that I can hide the parameters but still I fear the URL might be hacked so please suggest a way to secure.

2>Regarding the contents I want to encrypt the data and send to server and in server side it will be decrypted .

Now please suggest me an **algorithm** or **code** which can be used across platform like IOS,Android , .Net

Thanks and Regards,
Anil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use HTTPS
2. Use login/password auth (no access at all without login and
   password)

Comment: Hi basically I want to encrypt the contents but the algorithm for IOS,Android and .net is not matching.So please let me know that